How can I make a button inside of a frame affect something outside its own frame with Custom TKinter?
How can I make a button inside of a frame affect something outside its own frame? I am new to programming and have not been able to solve this problem on my own. Here is my code and some pictures showing exactly what I want to do. Any help would be appreciated.
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter


class SidebarFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, corner_radius=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Board Game\nBorrow", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))       #Title
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=(20, 10))

        self.functionsframe = FunctionsSidebarFrame(self)                                                                                 #Call Functions Frame
        self.functionsframe.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.functions_remove()                                                                                                           #Hide Functions Frame

        self.loginframe = LoginSidebarFrame(self)                                                                                         #Call Login Frame
        self.loginframe.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Login", command=self.login)
        self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

    def login_remove(self):
        self.loginframe.grid_remove()

    def login_show(self):
        self.loginframe.grid()

    def functions_remove(self):
        self.functionsframe.grid_remove()

    def functions_show(self):
        self.functionsframe.grid()

    def login(self):
        if self.loginframe.winfo_ismapped():
            self.login_remove()
            self.functions_show()
        elif not self.loginframe.winfo_ismapped():
            self.login_show()
            self.functions_remove()

class FunctionsSidebarFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, width=120, corner_radius=8)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

        self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Veiw Game List", command=self.viewGames)                                #Side Button 1 (View Game List)
        self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.sidebar_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Request Game", command=self.requestGame)                                #Side Button 2 (Request Game)
        self.sidebar_button_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.sidebar_button_3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Add Game", command=self.addGame)                                        #Side Button 3 (Add Game)
        self.sidebar_button_3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

    def viewGames(self):
        print("View Games")

    def requestGame(self):
        print("Request Game")

    def addGame(self):
        print("Add Game")

class LoginSidebarFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, width=120, corner_radius=8)

        text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Please Login", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=15, weight="bold"))                        #Title
        text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)


class ScrollFrame(customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)


        self._parent_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3, padx=(20,0), pady=(40,70), sticky="nsew")

        self.label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Game List", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=18, weight="bold"))
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20)
        # Add Game List here

class GeneralFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        
        label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Login Frame")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Board Game Borrow")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        self.sidebar_frame = SidebarFrame(self)                                                                                             #Call Sidebar Frame
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew")

        self.top_button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Create Account", width=15, height=10, command=self.create_account)                                                              #Top Button
        self.top_button1.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=(20, 80), pady=10, sticky="ne")

        self.top_button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Sign In", width=15, height=10, command=self.login)                                                 #Top Button
        self.top_button2.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="ne")

        self.checkbox = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(self, text="Sidebar", command=self.sidebar)                                               #Call Checkbox
        self.checkbox.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="ws")
        self.checkbox.select()

        self.textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self, width=100)                                                                            #Call Textbox
        self.textbox.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20, pady=(40,70), sticky="nsew", rowspan=3, columnspan=2)
        self.textbox.insert("end", "Welcome to Board Game Borrow\n\n")

        self.exit = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Exit", command=self.quit)                                                           #Exit Button
        self.exit.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="es")

        self.current_frame = None

        button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Switch to Scroll Frame", command=lambda: self.switch_frame(ScrollFrame))
        button1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="es")

        button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Switch to Login Frame", command=lambda: self.switch_frame(GeneralFrame))
        button2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=180, pady=20, sticky="es")

        button3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Remove Frame", command=lambda: self.remove_frame())
        button3.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="es")

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self.current_frame is not None:
            self.current_frame.grid_remove()
        self.current_frame = new_frame
        self.current_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)
        print(self.current_frame)

    def remove_frame(self):
        self.current_frame.grid_remove()
        self.current_frame = None
        print(self.current_frame)

    def sidebar_button_event(self):
        print("sidebar_button click")

    def sidebar(self):
        if self.sidebar_frame.winfo_ismapped():
            self.hide_sidebar()
        elif not self.sidebar_frame.winfo_ismapped():
            self.show_sidebar()
    
    def hide_sidebar(self):
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_remove()

    def show_sidebar(self):
        self.sidebar_frame.grid()

    def create_account(self):
        username = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Enter usernsme", title="Login")
        text1 = username.get_input()  # waits for input
        password = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Enter password", title="Login")
        text2 = password.get_input() # waits for input
        # Add code to add username(text1) and password(text2) to a new user in the database

    def login(self):
        username = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Enter usernsme", title="Login")
        text = username.get_input()  # waits for input
        password = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Enter password", title="Login")
        text2 = password.get_input() # waits for input
        if text == "admin" and text2 == "admin":
            self.top_button2.grid_remove()
            self.top_button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Sign Out", width=15, height=10)
            self.top_button2.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="ne")
            self.sidebar_frame.login()

    def __str__(self):
        return "App"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

The View Game List button should have the same functionality as the Switch to Scroll Frame Button
These are the buttons
Here is what the Switch to Scroll Frame Button does
I tried to have the button run App.switch_frame(ScrollFrame) but nothing happened. there was no error message or any kind of change.

I assume you want to reuse the switch_frame function in the viewGames function.
For this to work, you need to use an instance of your App class (app in lowercase).
Then clicking the "View Game List" button will do the same thing as clicking the "Switch to Scroll Frame" button.
The app and ScrollFrame names are defined in the same space as the FunctionsSidebarFrame class.
def viewGames(self):
    print("View Games")
    app.switch_frame(ScrollFrame)
    # or
    # self.master.master.switch_frame(ScrollFrame)

However, the way you switch frames in the switch_frame function creates new objects every time the function is called.
new_frame = frame_class(self) # new object
if self.current_frame is not None:
    self.current_frame.grid_remove() # hide the previous frame, but it still exists
self.current_frame = new_frame
self.current_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

If you add print(self.winfo_children()) to the remove_frame function, you'll see a group of frame objects at the end of the list (after ".!ctkbutton6").
The number of objects depends on how many times the user clicks the buttons that call the switch_frame function.
To make the buttons switch frames instead of creating new ones, you need to change the switch_frame function.
Changes:

Create one instance of GeneralFrame and one instance of ScrollFrame in __init__ (class App).
Use grid_remove to hide frames.
Pass frames (not classes) as arguments to commands.
Make a specific instance visible in the switch_frame function.

Full code:
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter


class SidebarFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, corner_radius=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Board Game\nBorrow", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))       #Title
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=(20, 10))

        self.functionsframe = FunctionsSidebarFrame(self)                                                                                 #Call Functions Frame
        self.functionsframe.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.functions_remove()                                                                                                           #Hide Functions Frame

        self.loginframe = LoginSidebarFrame(self)                                                                                         #Call Login Frame
        self.loginframe.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Login", command=self.login)
        self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

    def login_remove(self):
        self.loginframe.grid_remove()

    def login_show(self):
        self.loginframe.grid()

    def functions_remove(self):
        self.functionsframe.grid_remove()

    def functions_show(self):
        self.functionsframe.grid()

    def login(self):
        if self.loginframe.winfo_ismapped():
            self.login_remove()
            self.functions_show()
        elif not self.loginframe.winfo_ismapped():
            self.login_show()
            self.functions_remove()

class FunctionsSidebarFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, width=120, corner_radius=8)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        
        self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="View Game List", command=self.viewGames)                                #Side Button 1 (View Game List)
        self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.sidebar_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Request Game", command=self.requestGame)                                #Side Button 2 (Request Game)
        self.sidebar_button_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.sidebar_button_3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Add Game", command=self.addGame)                                        #Side Button 3 (Add Game)
        self.sidebar_button_3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

    def viewGames(self):
        print("View Games")
        # updated part
        app.switch_frame(app.scroll_frame.master.master)
        # In the case of classes defined in different namespaces, you can use this:
        # self.master.master.switch_frame(self.master.master.scroll_frame.master.master)
        # print(self.master.master) # App
        # end of updated part

    def requestGame(self):
        print("Request Game")

    def addGame(self):
        print("Add Game")

class LoginSidebarFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, width=120, corner_radius=8)

        text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Please Login", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=15, weight="bold"))                        #Title
        text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)


class ScrollFrame(customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        # updated part
        # parent .!ctkframe
        self._parent_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=3, padx=(20,0), pady=(40,70), sticky="nsew")
        # print(self.master.master is self._parent_frame) # True
        # end of updated part
        
        self.label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Game List", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=18, weight="bold"))
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20)
        # Add Game List here

class GeneralFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        
        # updated part
        self.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=3, padx=(20,0), pady=(40,70), sticky="nsew")
        # end of updated part
        label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Login Frame")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Board Game Borrow")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        self.sidebar_frame = SidebarFrame(self)                                                                                             #Call Sidebar Frame
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew")

        self.top_button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Create Account", width=15, height=10, command=self.create_account)                                                              #Top Button
        self.top_button1.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=(20, 80), pady=10, sticky="ne")

        self.top_button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Sign In", width=15, height=10, command=self.login)                                                 #Top Button
        self.top_button2.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="ne")

        self.checkbox = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(self, text="Sidebar", command=self.sidebar)                                               #Call Checkbox
        self.checkbox.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="ws")
        self.checkbox.select()

        self.textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self, width=100)                                                                            #Call Textbox
        self.textbox.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20, pady=(40,70), sticky="nsew", rowspan=3, columnspan=2)
        self.textbox.insert("end", "Welcome to Board Game Borrow\n\n")

        self.exit = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Exit", command=self.quit)                                                           #Exit Button
        self.exit.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="es")

        self.current_frame = None

        # updated part
        # create objects:
        # <__main__.GeneralFrame object .!generalframe>
        # <customtkinter.windows.widgets.ctk_frame.CTkFrame object .!ctkframe>
        
        self.login_frame = GeneralFrame(self)
        self.login_frame.grid_remove()

        self.scroll_frame = ScrollFrame(self)
        # print(self.scroll_frame) # .!ctkframe.!canvas.!scrollframe
        self.scroll_frame.master.master.grid_remove() # hide parent .!ctkframe
        # print(self.scroll_frame.master.master) # .!ctkframe

        button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Switch to Scroll Frame", command=lambda: self.switch_frame(self.scroll_frame.master.master))
        button1.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="es")

        button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Switch to Login Frame", command=lambda: self.switch_frame(self.login_frame))
        button2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=180, pady=20, sticky="es")
        # end of updated part

        button3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Remove Frame", command=lambda: self.remove_frame())
        button3.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="es")
        
    # updated part
    def switch_frame(self, frame):
        """
        :param frame: instance of customtkinter.CTkFrame
        """
        if self.current_frame is frame:
            return
        if self.current_frame is not None:
            self.current_frame.grid_remove()
        # display an existing object
        self.current_frame = frame
        self.current_frame.grid() # grid options are remembered
        print(self.current_frame)

    def remove_frame(self):
        if self.current_frame is None:
            return
        self.current_frame.grid_remove()
        self.current_frame = None
        print(self.current_frame)
        print(self.winfo_children())
    # end of updated part
    
    def sidebar_button_event(self):
        print("sidebar_button click")

    def sidebar(self):
        if self.sidebar_frame.winfo_ismapped():
            self.hide_sidebar()
        elif not self.sidebar_frame.winfo_ismapped():
            self.show_sidebar()
    
    def hide_sidebar(self):
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_remove()

    def show_sidebar(self):
        self.sidebar_frame.grid()

    def create_account(self):
        username = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Enter usernsme", title="Login")
        text1 = username.get_input()  # waits for input
        password = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Enter password", title="Login")
        text2 = password.get_input() # waits for input
        # Add code to add username(text1) and password(text2) to a new user in the database

    def login(self):
        username = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Enter usernsme", title="Login")
        text = username.get_input()  # waits for input
        password = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Enter password", title="Login")
        text2 = password.get_input() # waits for input
        if text == "admin" and text2 == "admin":
            self.top_button2.grid_remove()
            self.top_button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Sign Out", width=15, height=10)
            self.top_button2.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="ne")
            self.sidebar_frame.login()

    def __str__(self):
        return "App"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()


What you tried, App.switch_frame(ScrollFrame) , won't work because it is calling the function from the class not the instance, which is not the window you are seeing. So you need to call the function from the instance 'app'.
This is the general problem with OOP. You often need the classes to interact in some way which is only possible if each had a reference to the other or the instances were global. Both solutions defeat the purpose/advantage of using OOP.
For your case, you could give the class FunctionsSidebarFrame a reference to the app instance which you can then use to call its swith_frame function.
class FunctionsSidebarFrame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, app):
        self.app = app
        ...
    def viewGames(self):
        self.app.switch_frame(ScrollFrame)

This will also require you to give the class SidebarFrame the reference to be passed to FunctionsSidebarFrame.
